# NSString padding / space between 2 characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsstring, nsarray

I'm looking for an easy way in Objective-C to do add a space between every 2 characters of my string. So "12345678" would come out looking like "12 34 56 78".

Other way, convert the string(a 128bit long string with all numbers) into a array with every 2 characters.

Does anyone know of something to help me?

Thanks. - Eli

Comment: An NSMutableString and a loop?

Comment: Can you teach me how to achieve this? I'm new to Objective-C, thanks! @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: @EliLien You have to make some effort yourself. Embrace the hint you got from Joachim and read the documentation of `NSMutableString`. This is **trivial** and requires nothing more than some simple algorithmic thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    NSString *str = @"12345678";
    NSMutableString *tempStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (int position=0; position < str.length; position++) {

        if(position%2==0)
        {
            [tempStr appendString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:position]]];
        }
        else
        {
            [tempStr appendString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:position]]];

            NSLog(@"%@\n",tempStr);
            [tempStr setString:@""];
        }
    }
    [tempStr release];
```

Comment: This invokes undefined behavior. `- [NSString characterAtIndex:]` returns `unichar` for which the format specifier is `%C` and not `%c`.

Comment: thanks for the info sir...It worked with %c also..anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *str = @"12345678";
NSMutableString* mStr= [NSMutableString string];
for(NSUInteger i=0 ; i<str.length; i++)
{
    [mStr appendString: [str substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i,1)]];
    if(i%2 && i!=0)
    {
        [mStr appendString: @" "];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",mStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have come to a solution, this is just another example (and not an particularly effective one at that) how it can be done. This version handles an odd number of characters correctly;

```
NSString *original = @"192190129";
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:2*original.length];

for (int pos=0; pos < original.length; pos++) {

    NSString *formatToAppend = (pos && !(pos & 1)) ? @" %C" : @"%C";
    [result appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:formatToAppend,
        [original characterAtIndex:pos]]];

}

>>> "19 21 90 12 9"
```

Writing (or at least reading and understanding) code like this yourself is very good training if you're a beginner, and there are many ways of doing it so you can try a few ways to see what code style you like.